# How can I move focus to next field after enterd previous field without click on new field retain keyboard in Xamarin PCL project?

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After one has enter log on information e.g. UserName,Password if its possible to add the NeXT possibility so one doesn't have to press Return, keyboard disappears, and I need to tap With the mouse again to Write in NeXT Field.

How can I Focus and retain keyboard to next field in xamarin pcl project?

ex: I have UserName and Password field on my xamarin XAML view.
    after i entered userName i want to set focus to Password field and without    click on the password field  should appear the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the completed event.

```
        UsernameField.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            UsernameField.Unfocus();
            PasswordField.Focus();

        };
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this from XAML itself?

Comment: This works but there is a movement from the keyboard. Keyboard tries to hide but after focusing on the next field, it shows again. There's this awkward situation between unfocusing from current field to the next field